# apc_add() versus apc_store()

Tags: php, apc

I know that apc_store() overwrites the key if it already exists, so I know the difference, my question is just: What's the better method/best practice?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The only difference between those two functions is that [**`apc_add()`**](http://fr.php.net/apc_add) will not overwrite an existing entry.

[**`apc_store()`**](http://fr.php.net/apc_store), on the other hand, will overwrite an existing entry.

So, which one should your use, between `apc_add()` and `apc_store()` ?

Well, it all depends on your needs : do you want an existing entry to be overwritten, or not ?

Comment: A result of this difference might have major implications in concurrent environments: excessive locking, resulting with extremely high latencies or crashes (I've added another answer relating to this)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @Pascal MARTIN writes, there is a major practical difference between them.

In a heavily concurrent environment, e.g. when using apc for user objects in apache, the use of apc_store might lead to [apc time bomb](http://notmysock.org/blog/php/user-cache-timebomb.html) (the link is from 2007 but still relevant!), while apc_add mitigates this issue.

See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/342295/apc-keeps-crashing

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on the logic you need to apply: do you need to overwrite the key or not? It’s all up to you.

Comment: Then there's a page fault in your memory.

Answer (score 1):

you need `apc_add()` in case you like to implement an atomic counter in a concurrent environment. thats the main use-case IMO.